# Looping through an XML file to store in to a CSV using C#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

In my Project I am using a time log api, which includes a long XML file including emplyee id, name, company name, id etc. Now I want to store that XML properties into a CSV file with heading of that propertyname. For example Emaployee name, Employee id,etc. With my code I the looping of the XML file is now working. It gives all error messages, sometimes one value in more times.

The XML file of my Project

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tlp:WorkUnits xmlns:tlp="http://www.timelog.com/XML/Schema/tlp/v4_4"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.timelog.com/XML/Schema/tlp/v4_4 http://www.timelog.com/api/xsd/WorkUnitsRaw.xsd">
  <tlp:WorkUnit ID="130">
    <tlp:EmployeeID>3</tlp:EmployeeID>
    <tlp:AllocationID>114</tlp:AllocationID>
    <tlp:TaskID>239</tlp:TaskID>
    <tlp:ProjectID>26</tlp:ProjectID>
    <tlp:ProjectName>LIK Template</tlp:ProjectName>  
  </tlp:WorkUnit>
```

I have A workunit Class where I the properties are declared for XML.

Now I create a class where I want to loop through the XML and store that file into CSv, But nothing is showing properly.

Here is that class

```
    namespace TimeLog.ApiConsoleApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Template class for consuming the reporting API
    /// </summary>
    public class ConsumeReportingApi
    {
        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ConsumeReportingApi));

        public static void Consume()
        {
            if (ServiceHandler.Instance.TryAuthenticate())
            {
                if (Logger.IsInfoEnabled)
                {
                    Logger.Info("Successfully authenticated on reporting API");
                }

                var customersRaw = ServiceHandler.Instance.Client.GetWorkUnitsRaw(ServiceHandler.Instance.SiteCode,
                     ServiceHandler.Instance.ApiId,
                     ServiceHandler.Instance.ApiPassword,

                  );



                if (customersRaw.OwnerDocument != null)
                {
                     var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(customersRaw.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
                namespaceManager.AddNamespace("tlp", "http://www.timelog.com/XML/Schema/tlp/v4_4");
                var workUnit = customersRaw.SelectNodes("tlp:WorkUnit", namespaceManager);


                    if (workUnit != null)
                    {
                        var output = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (XmlNode customer in workUnit)
                        {
                            var unit = new WorkUnit();
                            var childNodes = customer.SelectNodes("./*");

                            if (childNodes != null)
                            {
                                foreach (XmlNode childNode in childNodes)
                                {
                                    if (childNode.Name == "tlp:EmployeeID")
                                    {

                                        unit.EmployeeID = Int32.Parse(childNode.InnerText);
                                     }
                                    if (childNode.Name == "tlp:EmployeeFirstName")
                                    {
                                        unit.ProjectName = childNode.InnerText;
                                    }
                                    if (childNode.Name == "tlp:EmployeeLastName")
                                    {
                                        unit.ProjectName = childNode.InnerText;
                                    }

                                    if (childNode.Name == "tlp:AllocationID")
                                    {
                                        unit.ProjectName = childNode.InnerText;
                                    }

                                    if (childNode.Name == "tlp:TaskName")
                                    {
                                        unit.ProjectName = childNode.InnerText;
                                    }

                                }



                            output.AppendLine($"{unit.EmployeeID},{unit.EmployeeFirstName},{unit.EmployeeLastName},{unit.AllocationID},{unit.TaskName}");

                            }

                            Console.WriteLine(output.AppendLine($"{unit.EmployeeID},{unit.EmployeeFirstName},{unit.EmployeeLastName},{unit.AllocationID},{unit.TaskName}"));

                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    if (Logger.IsWarnEnabled)
                    {
                        Logger.Warn("Failed to authenticate to reporting API");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My OutPut file looks like this

```
    387,,,-1,

387,,,-1,
388,,,-1,

387,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,

387,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,

387,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,

387,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,

387,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
410,,,-1,

387,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
388,,,-1,
410,,,-1,
447,,,-1,
```

Answer (score 0):

Append `childNode.InnerText` to the `StringBuilder` in each iteration:

```
var workUnit = customersRaw.SelectNodes("tlp:WorkUnit", namespaceManager);
if (workUnit != null)
{
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (XmlNode customer in workUnit)
    {
        //var unit = new WorkUnit();
        var childNodes = customer.SelectNodes("./*");
        if (childNodes != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<childNodes.Count; ++i)
            {
                XmlNode childNode = childNodes[i];
                /*if (childNode.Name == "tlp:EmployeeID")
                {
                    unit.EmployeeID = Int32.Parse(childNode.InnerText);
                }
                if (childNode.Name == "tlp:EmployeeFirstName")
                {
                    unit.ProjectName = childNode.InnerText;
                }
                if (childNode.Name == "tlp:EmployeeLastName")
                {
                    unit.ProjectName = childNode.InnerText;
                }

                if (childNode.Name == "tlp:AllocationID")
                {
                    unit.ProjectName = childNode.InnerText;
                }

                if (childNode.Name == "tlp:TaskName")
                {
                    unit.ProjectName = childNode.InnerText;
                }*/
                output.Append(childNode.InnerText);
                if(i<childNodes.Count - 1)
                    output.Append(",");
            }
            output.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @tamrezh21: Did you try this?  It seems like you did based on the code you posted in your latest question. Please remember to accept the answer and vote it up if your issue has been solved.

Answer (score -2):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string XML_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string CSV_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XML_FILENAME);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(CSV_FILENAME);

            XElement firstWorkUnit = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "WorkUnit").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = firstWorkUnit.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("tlp");


            List<XElement> workUnits = doc.Descendants(ns + "WorkUnit").ToList();
            foreach (XElement workUnit in workUnits)
            {
                string outputline = string.Join(",", new string[] {
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "EmployeeID"),
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "AllocationID"),
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "TaskID"),
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "ProjectID"),
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "ProjectName"),
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "CustomerId"),
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "CustomerName"),
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "IsBillable"),
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "ApprovedStatus"),
                    (string)workUnit.Element(ns + "LastModifiedBy")
                });

                writer.WriteLine(outputline);
            }

            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @jdwengI have xml from web link that I gave. Thank you. but your solution is colpletely diferent from my code. how can I correct my code to get the correct value

Comment: I think your code is missing the namespaces and recommend you use my code which is more efficient.